# I can't connect to my friends Minecraft world

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When ever my friend sends me an invite to her world I click "accept" and it tells me that it is syncing the pack to the server but then a message shows up that says `cannot connect to world`. But whenever I invite her to my worlds, she can connect.

We're using Minecraft PE on our phones. I have an Iphone 6s, and she has a Samsung S6 Edge.

Is there anything I could do to connect to her world?

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of ideas:

- Restart the world/the app on both phones
- Make sure both phones are on the same Wi-Fi network
- Make sure both phones are on the same update
- Try going into settings and enabling "Local server multiplayer"

Hope this helped!